# Bioche's rules in the integration

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, change-of-variable

Looking this question [Indefinite integral $\int \frac{1}{1+\sin^4\left(x\right)}dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4070996/indefinite-integral-int-frac11-sin4-leftx-rightdx) and the comment of the nice user @Bernard for the use of the substitution

$$t=\tan x$$

On [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bioche%27s_rules#:%7E:text=Bioche%27s%20rules%2C%20formulated%20by%20the,integrand%20contains%20sines%20and%20cosines.&text=%2C%20under%20translation%20and%20reflections%20of%20the%20t%20axis) there are some examples when it is necessary to use the

If
$$\omega (-t)=\omega (t)$$
a good change of variables is $u=\cos t$ (even function).

If
$$\omega (\pi -t)=\omega (t)$$
a good change of variables is $u=\sin t$ (odd function).
If
$$\omega (\pi +t)=\omega (t)$$
a good change of variables is $u=\tan t$.

If two of the preceding relations both hold, a good change of variables is
$$u=\cos 2t$$

In all other cases, use
$$u=\tan(t/2)$$

> Why @Bernard have used $t=\tan x$ if have an even integrand function? Shouldn't you use cosine $u=\cos t$?

PS: Never I have studied the Bioche's rules in the integration during the period at the university.

Comment: If you had to evaluate $\int\cos tdt$, $u=\cos t$ wouldn't help much.

Comment: @J.G. Hi :-)...I have not read well the wikipedia site :-(

Comment: The point  is that it is not the integrand which has to be invariant by one of these transformations, but the *differential form* $f(t)\,\mathrm dt$.

Comment: @Bernard hiiiiiiiiiiiiii..always thank you also for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Wikipedia notes, $\omega$ includes the $dt$ factor, say $\omega=fdt$, so $\omega(c-t)=\omega(t)$ if $f(c-t)=-f(t)$.

Comment: Why is it necessary to use $\omega$ and remains only $f$? So how are they supposed to write better if you don't use$\omega(t)=f(x)dt$? Please can you edit your answer thus have I the corrected rules?

Comment: @Sebastiano I think what you're asking is addressed in the Wikipedia paragraph beginning "because", where they note that using $\omega$ makes for a helpful mnemonic, because $\omega$ satisfies the same constraints as the choice of $u$ thereby mandated. For example, it's less easy to remember $f$ being odd makes an even substitution useful.

Comment: Always thankssssssssssssssss.